# R GGMAP HTTP 400 Bad Request

Tags: r, ggmap

I'm trying to follow the following tutorial https://www.r-bloggers.com/mapping-seattle-crime/, but not able to load the GGMAP.

I have already activated the Google API and registered using register_google(). But I'm getting the following error after calling GGMAP

`map_city <- qmap(location = "seattle", zoom = 11, source="stamen", maptype="toner",darken = c(.3,"#BBBBBB"))`

````
Error in aperm.default(map, c(2, 1, 3)) : 
  invalid first argument, must be an array
In addition: Warning message:
In get_googlemap(center = location, zoom = zoom, filename = filename) :
  HTTP 400 Bad Request ```

How can I resolve? Thanks.
````

Comment: Just checking: did you enable geocaching in your google API? Google now charges money for this.